# Unknown reason for AV inside a procedure

Tags: delphi

I created an empty unit to store my public procedures and functions but I get access violation in the first line of a procedure, but this for the first time only I call this procedure, later calls work normally !!

The unit code:

```
unit myFunc;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, System.UITypes, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms;

  Procedure GSet(grid_form: TForm; app, operation: string);

implementation

Procedure GSet(grid_form: TForm; app, operation: string);
var
grd_idx: integer;
begin
  if operation = 'save' then begin  // Access violation in this line 

    if (grid_form.components[grd_idx] is TMyComponent) then
    (grid_form.components[grd_idx] as TMyComponent).Storedata('c:\'+app);
  end;
end;
```

**Update:**
I call this procedure from form create event like this

```
GridSettings(myform, 'cost', 'save');
```

Comment: Please show a complete program. I don't mean your complete program. I mean a short complete program that shows the fault.

Comment: This code cannot possibly cause an AV, which means that the problem is elsewhere (such as the code that is calling this procedure). As you provided no information about that code, it's impossible to tell where, or why that code is causing the problem.

Comment: This is really all the code, it is small procedure...however I will try to initialize the grd_idx !

Comment: It is not all of the code. It is not a complete program that we can run.

Comment: @Wel After your edit, you seem to be asking a new question now. You can't edit your existing questions to ask something else. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in the question, the most obvious mistake is that the variable `grd_idx` is not initialised. You must initialise variables before using them.

On top of that it is possible that you are passing an invalid object reference in the first parameter. We cannot tell from here. However, it is possible that you are passing a global variable that has not been initialised. It looks awfully like you should be passing `Self` rather than that global variable.

```
GridSettings(Self, 'cost', 'save');
```

Of course, I am assuming here that `Self` is what you intend to pass here. Since you did not supply very much code, we can only guess as to the details of your code.

You ask how to make the `OnCreate` event fire after all controls are created. Well, that is already the case. The `OnCreate` method is fired after the controls are created and their properties streamed in.

I would also comment that using strings to select discrete options is not a good idea. Use enumerated types for that.

Comment: Tried initialize grd_idx but did not solve the problem. I then used `self` which worked in `OnCreate` event without raising AV, but why the form name `myform` raised this error ? .......thanks

Comment: Because the global variable is not assigned a value until the constructor returns. FWIW I delete all global form variables. They are a very bad idea that date back to early versions of VB.